# Making table row height not changing, when increasing the whole table height

Tags: html, css, css-tables

When I increase the table height, all the rows get resized and the additional height is distributed equally. among them.

### Question

Is it possible to make a row (in my example the one with headers) always stay at it's minimum height? As an analogy I see it as specifying `flex-grow: 0` on a Flex item.

### No fixed height

I don't want to make that row fixed height (e.g. set on it `height: <fixed value in px>`), just make it's height the natural minimum to render all the contents.

### Code

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzL4t6h0/11/) with the example code to work on. Screenshot below.

I want to make the first row in the right table (`.Table-Row--NotResizable`) to be the same height as the first row in the left table.

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div class="TableDisplay">
  <table class="Table Table--Natural">
    <tr>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Song</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prince</td>
      <td>Kiss</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Bob Dylan</td>
      <td>Idiot Wind</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="Table Table--Full">
    <tr class="Table-Row--NotResizable">
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Song</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prince</td>
      <td>Kiss</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Bob Dylan</td>
      <td>Idiot Wind</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.TableDisplay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.Table {
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.Table td,
.Table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Table--Full {
  height: 100%;
}

.Table--Natural {
  height: auto;
}

/* Make this row do not participate in height changes */
.Table-Row--NotResizable {
   /* ??? */
}
```

Comment: You can set the row to `height: 1px;` and it will for it to render the minimum height

Comment: Please don't ignore the rules of SO links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question

Comment: @Pete Okay, didn't know about that. I also thought that in that question posting all the code actually makes the problem less clear than more. Still I'll do that the next time.

Comment: It's because SO is meant to be a repository for future visitors, if the link goes dead then no one can see the code for your problem so the question becomes a bit useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact fixed value in px is exactly what you should use:

```
.Table-Row--NotResizable {
    height: 1px;
}
```

If you set it to 1px then the browser will resize it to exactly the size needed to fit the content. Table content has to fit into table cell, so the height will not be smaller, and as any (non-empty) content will be higher than 1px it will also not be greater than minimum needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been scratching my head at this for ages but I finally found a solution that works for me which slightly differs from the current answer.
In order to prevent each `<Tr>` from resizing to match the `<Table>` height, I set the height of each of my `<Tr>` to `1px`, however, to stop these rows from resizing, I had to **add an empty final `<Tr>` that does not contain any data to the end of my `<Table>`**. It seems this behaviour is because the `<Table>` element by default needs the `<Tr>` elements to sum up to the total height  of the table, and the empty `<Tr>` element stretches to fill this height whilst the rows containing data can be sized to their content.